Azure Cloud Service multiple work roles listening on different ports
I am working on a service that runs on Azure Cloud Service Extended Support.
My team needs to expose a new API and for various reasons it needs to be a new role within the existing Cloud Service.
The existing cloud service is already listening for incoming traffic on port 443.
The idea was to create a new role and simply add to csdef:
<Endpoints> 
    <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="8443" />
</Endpoints>

For reasons unknown, when deployed, all requests to port 8443 timeout.
Does anyone know, if it is even possible to achieve this with cloud services?
